# What does “belief” mean in the context of The Equalities Act 2010?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-terms, religion

[The Equalities Act of 2010](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/contents) (applicable in England, Scotland and Wales) says at [Section 10 (in part)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/section/10):

> Belief means any religious or philosophical belief; and a reference to
>   belief includes a reference to a lack of belief.

It goes on to describe, in [Section 26](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/section/26), harassment which includes the following:

> A person (A) harasses another (B) - if A engages in unwanted conduct
>   related to a relevant characteristic, and the conduct has the purpose
>   or effect of violating B’s dignity or creating an intimidating,
>   hostile, degrading, humiliating or offensive environment for B.

This seems quite broad. Would a belief that all female short lists are ethical be considered a belief in terms of this act? Or indeed a belief such as “the sky is not blue”? Or indeed *any* idea subscribed to.

If I was to argue with a coworker that the sky is not red but blue, and he takes offense, am I breaking the law?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key limiting factors are the language:

> and the conduct has the purpose or effect of violating B’s dignity or
>   creating an intimidating, hostile, degrading, humiliating or offensive
>   environment for B.

And, also, the context of the term "belief" in the statute in conjunction with religion which is defined in the same section, which suggests that in this context it is intended to be understood as the kind of belief that constitutes a core worldview for a person, even if it is secular (e.g. Confucianism or a Stoic philosophy of life), rather than isolated particular ideas about factual things.

There is also considerable room for judicial interpretation over whether, for example "effect of" is limited to an "effect" reasonably derived from the "conduct" in question.

Still, in general, the U.K., has higher standards mandating civility in dealings with others than the U.S., and there is lots of conduct barred by the Equality Act of 2010 which would not be barred under U.S. law, for example.

The closest analog in U.S. law is really the tort of "[outrageous conduct](http://injury.findlaw.com/torts-and-personal-injuries/intentional-infliction-of-emotional-distress.html)" also sometimes known as "intentional infliction of emotional distress."

Comment: Thank you. “...and the conduct has the purpose or effect of violating...”. By “or effect” this is unusually broad because a person can never be sure of effect. If I kill a someone, the purpose of my conduct matters (eg administering pain relief, that unintentionally killed). But in this law, if someone accidentally creates an offensive environment, they are breaking the law? Also, a great deal can be argued is a core worldview. For example: a position on all-female short lists can be said to be a core worldview? By covering so many modes of interaction, is this law in danger of overreach?

Comment: In theory, perhaps, but in practice, in a society like that of the U.K., people don't accidentally act in ways that violate someone's dignity or create an intimidating, hostile, degrading, humiliating or offensive environment. It is highly unlikely that a well behaved Brit would create those kinds of very extreme effects in practice by accident.

Comment: Accidentally causing offense to others’ worldview happens all the time does it not? If I say to someone “religion X supports terrorism”, and the other person, unbeknownst to me is of that religion, they take offense and I fall foul of the law. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Ben Merely causing offense doesn't violate the law. Creating an "offensive environment" is something much more pervasive than merely causing offense on a one off basis.

Comment: Ok thank you for that clarification. If I support view X and mention it frequently, say during office lunches without realising that a colleague finds such a view offensive, am I breaking the law?

Comment: @Ben Possibly. But, I doubt that something that is considered an "offensive environment" is something that could be easily overlooked by someone who isn't autistic. (On the other hand, someone on the ASD spectrum might very well have absolutely no clue.)

Comment: People hide their offense all the time. It’s part of the social facade each person relys upon to grease human interaction. It’s hidden, so we don’t need to rely on ASD as an excusatory. The environment (in this case group lunches at the office) might be highly offensive to a colleague without anyone knowing until the colleague reports the issue, at which point the company is empowered by this legislation to even terminate his employment. After all he was technically breaking the law at work. All without him have ever (until his firing) being aware he was doing so.

Comment: The more likely scenario is that an employee who secretly “takes offense” at another’s worldview, reports the offense with a view to forcing the offender to either resign or be fired. Under this Act, the employer is liable for the offense and so must act or be liable for not doing so. The seems to be wide scope for abuse.

Comment: @Ben Taken offense "secretly" would greatly undermine the claim that the environment was really an "offensive environment" on the merits.

Comment: Thank you. Your interpretation seems sensible, but the text of the law does not actually say that is the interpretation to be used. Is all law like this? The meaning of the word “environment” seems important in this context. On what do you base your interpretation of the text in the law?

Comment: @Ben There are many laws that call for significant interpretation. Some of it comes from key words in the text like "environment", some of it comes from the overall structure of the law, some of it comes from case law (which I don't have the resources to review in the case of English law), some of it comes from how similar issues in other laws are resolved and from "canons of statutory interpretation". As a general matter, the British statutory drafting style leaves more unstated for a judge to read into the text than most U.S. statutory drafting and trusts judges to use good sense more often.

Comment: Do you think that this law could have a chilling effect on our ability to communicate? After all causing offense is sometimes a first step in developing a shared understanding or piquing interest.

Comment: ...offense also has an important role in some humour...

Comment: @Ben British people are already chillier than a frozen alligator stifled as they are by their manners and stiff upper lips in communications with each other. This is the land of "stay calm and carry on." The law is an expression of this British cultural understanding about appropriate public communications, not an interference with it. It is hard to imagine how it could be further inhibited.

Comment: That is a stereotype that may be true for some, but certainly not for all Brits. Why encode such stifling of expression in law? I view this legislation as too all-encompassing.

Comment: The reference to the British character fails to account for the Brit John Stewart Mill, a famous advocate for freedom of expression. Furthermore art can also be said to create an offensive environment: eg. the Sensation Art Exhibition (1997).